# OpenGL - Using texture's alpha channel AND a "global" opacity level

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to get a fairly simple effect; I'd like my sprites to be able to have their alpha channels used by GL (that is, translucent across parts of the image, but not all of it) as well as the entire sprite to have an "opacity" level that affects the entire sprite.

I've got the latter part, that was a simple enough matter of using GL_MODULATE and passing a color4d(opacity, opacity, opacity, opacity). Works like a dream.

But the problem is in the first part; partially translucent images. I'd thought that i could just fling out a glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); and enable blending, but unfortunately it doesn't do it. What it seems to do is "whiten" the color of the image in question, rather than making it translucent. Any other sprites passing under it behave as if it were a solid block of color, and get directly cut off.

For reference, i've disabled lighting, z-buffer, color material, and alpha test. Did shade model flat, just in case. But other than that, i'm using default ortho settings. I'm using teximage2d for the texture in question, and i've been sure the formats and GL_RGBA are all set correctly.

How can i get GL to consider the texture's alpha channel during blending?

Comment: Did you enable blending with glEnable? Also, to set opacity of a sprite, you don't need GL_MODULATE, just use color4d(1, 1, 1, alpha);

Comment: I agree with @Bahbar. What you've described should work (and does for me). I think if you posted some of your code it'd be helpful. One minor point: I think you should be using color4d(1, 1, 1, opacity). The color you're using means that the sprite will simultaneously get darker as it gets more transparent.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and fastest solution is to have a fragment shader.

```
uniform float alpha;
uniform sampler2D texture;
main(){
    gl_FragColor = texture2d(texture, gl_TexCoords);
    gl_FragColor.a *= alpha;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- GL_MODULATE is the way to tell GL to use the texture alpha for the final alpha of the fragment (it's also the default).
- Your blending is also correct as to how to use that generated alpha in the blending stage.

So the problem lies elsewhere... Your description sounds like you did not in fact disable Z-test, and you do not render your sprites back to front. Alpha blending in GL will only do what you want if you draw your sprites back to front. Otherwise, the sprites get blended in the wrong order, and this does not produce the correct output.

It would be easier to verify this with a picture of what you observe though.

Comment: I attempted the shader, without success.

Comment: I attempted the shader, without success. -- I also am quite positive that sprites are rendered back-to-front, since the Z-buffer is quite disabled. Were it not, absolutely no form of alpha would work correctly (currently only a 'per-sprite' opacity works). I should re-iterate on that note, that alpha appears to be binary. If the image's alpha completely masks out any section of the image. It essentially functions like a binary alpha channel, though i know for a fact that the images are in 32bit argb (which is of course swapped to rgba correctly).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but GL_MODULATE will cause the alphas of the texture and the underlying polygon to be multiplied together (which is of course what the original question is asking for).

Comment: @Rich: what GL_MODULATE does depends on what exactly the base texture format is. But for cases that do have alpha (I, A, LA, RGBA), yes they multiply. And yes, that's what he's asking for.